# building a lexical analyser using ml-lex

Tags: sml, ml, ml-lex

I need to create a new instance of a `lexer` tied to the standard input stream.
However, when I type in

```
val lexer = makeLexer( fn n => inputLine( stdIn ) );
```

I get an error that I don't understand:

```
stdIn:1.5-11.13 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: int -> string
  operand:         int -> string option
  in expression:
```

(`makeLexer` is a function name present in my source code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[inputLine](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/text-io.html#SIG%3aTEXT_IO.inputLine%3aVAL) returns a `string option`, and my guess is a `string` is expected.

What you want to do is either have `makeLexer` take a `string option`, like so:

```
fun makeLexer  NONE    = <whatever you want to do when stream is empty>
  | makeLexer (SOME s) = <the normal body makeLexer, working on the string s>
```

or change your line to:

```
val lexer = makeLexer( fn n => valOf ( inputLine( stdIn ) ) );
```

[valOf](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/option.html#SIG%3aOPTION.valOf%3aVAL) takes an option type and unpacks it.

Note that, since `inputLine` returns `NONE` when the stream is empty, it's probably a better idea to use the first approach, rather than the second.

Answer (score 2):

An example of how to make an interactive stream is given on page 38 (or 32 in the paper) of the [User's Guide to ML-Lex and ML-Yacc](http://rogerprice.org/ug/ug.pdf)

The example code could be simpler by using inputLine.
So I would use the example given by Sebastian, keeping in mind that inputLine might return NONE using stdIn atleast if the user presses CTRL-D.

```
val lexer =
let 
  fun input f =
      case TextIO.inputLine f of
        SOME s => s
      | NONE => raise Fail "Implement proper error handling."
in 
  Mlex.makeLexer (fn (n:int) => input TextIO.stdIn)
end
```

Also the calculator example on page 40 (34 in the paper) shows how to use this in a whole

In general the user guide contains some nice examples and explanations.