# How to use Start States in ML-Lex?

Tags: tokenize, sml, lex, ml-lex

I am creating a tokeniser in ML-Lex a part of the definition of which is

```
datatype lexresult = STRING
                     | STRINGOP
                     | EOF
val error = fn x => TextIO.output(TextIO.stdOut,x ^ "\n")
val eof = fn () => EOF

%%
%structure myLang
digit=[0-9];
ws=[\ \t\n];
str=\"[.*]+\";
strop=\[[0-9...?\^]\];
%s alpha;
alpha=[a-zA-Z];
%%

<alpha> {alphanum}+ => (ID);
. => (error ("myLang: ignoring bad character " ^ yytext); lex());
```

I want that the type ID should be detected only when it starts with or is found after "alpha". I know that writing it as

```
{alpha}+ {alphanum}* => (ID);
```

is an option but I need to learn to use the use of start states as well for some other purposes. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

The information you need is in [the documentation which comes with SML](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/ML-Lex/manual.html) available in various places. Many [university courses have online notes which contain working examples](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs421/lectureNotes/c02.pdf).

The first thing to note from your example code is that you have overloaded the name `alpha` and used it to name a *state* and a *pattern*. This is probably not a good idea. The pattern `alphanum` is not not defined, and the result `ID` is not declared. Some basic errors which you should probably fix before thinking about using states - or posting a question here on SO. Asking for help for code with such obvious faults in it is not encouraging help from the experts. :-)

Having fixed up those errors, we can start using states. Here is my version of your code:

```
datatype lexresult = ID
                     | EOF
val error = fn x => TextIO.output(TextIO.stdOut,x ^ "\n")
val eof = fn () => EOF

%%
%structure myLang
digit=[0-9];
ws=[\ \t\n];
str=\"[.*]+\";
strop=\[[0-9...?\^]\];
%s ALPHA_STATE;
alpha=[a-zA-Z];
alphanum=[a-zA-Z0-9];
%%

<INITIAL>{alpha} => (YYBEGIN ALPHA_STATE; continue());
<ALPHA_STATE>{alphanum}+ => (YYBEGIN INITIAL; TextIO.output(TextIO.stdOut,"ID\n"); ID);

. => (error ("myLang: ignoring bad character " ^ yytext); lex());
```

You can see I've added `ID` to the `lexresult`, named the state `ALPHA_STATE` and added the `alphanum` pattern. Now lets look at how the state code works:

There are two states in this program, they are called `INITIAL` and `ALPHA_STATE` (all lex programs have an `INITIAL` default state). It always begins recognising in the `INITIAL` state. Having a rule `<INITIAL>{alpha} =>` indicates that if you encounter a letter when in the initial state (i.e. NOT in the `ALPHA_STATE`) then it is a match and the action should be invoked. The action for this rule works as follows:

```
YYBEGIN ALPHA_STATE;          (* Switch from INITIAL state to ALPHA_STATE *)
continue()                    (* and keep going *)
```

Now we are in `ALPHA_STATE` it enables those rules defined for this state, which enable the rule `<ALPHA_STATE>{alphanum} =>`. The action on this rule switch back to the `INITIAL` state and record the match.

For a longer example of using states (lex rather than ML-lex) you can see my answer here: [Error while parsing comments in lex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317948/error-while-parsing-comments-in-lex/29818307#29818307).

To test this ML-LEX program I referenced this helpful question: [building a lexical analyser using ml-lex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794009/buliding-a-lexical-analyser-using-ml-lex), and generated the following SML program:

```
use "states.lex.sml";
open myLang
val lexer =
let 
  fun input f =
      case TextIO.inputLine f of
        SOME s => s
      | NONE => raise Fail "Implement proper error handling."
in 
  myLang.makeLexer (fn (n:int) => input TextIO.stdIn)
end
val nextToken = lexer();
```

and just for completeness, it generated the following output demonstrating the match:

```
c:\Users\Brian>"%SMLNJ_HOME%\bin\sml" main.sml
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.78 [built: Sun Dec 21 15:52:08 2014]
[opening main.sml]
[opening states.lex.sml]
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
structure myLang :
  sig
    structure UserDeclarations : <sig>
    exception LexError
    structure Internal : <sig>
    val makeLexer : (int -> string) -> unit -> Internal.result
  end
val it = () : unit
hello
ID
```